# Unable to call set Props in deck.gl while updating data

Tags: javascript, mapbox, deck.gl

I am new to Deck.gl and was basically trying to update the layers whenever the data changes with on change event listener call. I have tried the setProps function but it is still not working. Please let me know what i am doing wrong.

Here is the Code

```
  $('product_categories').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    var new_layers = [
      new TextLayer({
         id: 'text-layer2',
         data: GEOJSON_FILE,
         dataTransform: d => d.features,
         getPosition: f => f.geometry.coordinates,
         getText: f => f.properties.name,
         sizeScale: 1,
         getPixelOffset: [0, 15],
         getSize: d => 20,        
         getColor: [0,0,0]
         // backgroundColor: [0,0,0,0]
       }),
       new GeoJsonLayer({
         id: 'locations2',
         data: GEOJSON_FILE,
         // Styles
         filled: true,
         pointRadiusMinPixels: 2,
         pointRadiusScale: 2000,
         getRadius: f => 2,
         getFillColor: [200, 0, 80, 180],
         // Interactive props
         pickable: true,
         autoHighlight: true,
         controller: true,
         getTooltip: info => info.object && `${info.object.properties.name}\n${info.object.properties.description}`,
         onClick: info => info.object && alert(`${info.object.properties.description}`)
       }),
       new ArcLayer({
         id: 'arcs2',
         data: ARC_FILE,
         dataTransform: d => d.features.slice(3,5),
         // Styles
         getSourcePosition: f => f.from.coordinates, // London
         getTargetPosition: f => f.to.coordinates,
         pickable: true,
         autoHighlight: true,
         getSourceColor: info => get_color(info, ''),
         getTargetColor: info => get_color(info, 'target'),
         getWidth: d => parseInt(((stop - start) * ((d.properties.volume - v_min) / (v_max - v_min))) + start)
       })
    ]
    console.log(deck.props.layers[2])
    deck.setProps({layers: new_layers});
    console.log(deck.props.layers[2]);
  });
```

After i do setProps, the layer lifecycle appears as "Matched. State transferred from previous layer" and nothing happens on screen.

Any kind of help in this regard would be very much appreciated.
Thanks.